# Centrar texto a la mitad de una altura en un botón y adaptarlo su longitud variable (HTML y CSS)

Tags: html5, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si me expliqué bien en el titulo pero este es mi problema: tengo una etiqueta `nav` que contiene al texto y deseo colocarla en medio de la altura de la imagen. Todo está dentro de un botón y el texto también será variable, por lo que el botón tiene que ajustarse a ello. Recién estoy empezando a ver `CSS` y `HTML` por lo que me es aún un poco difícil hacerlo para mi.

Gracias por su apoyo.

Mi código:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*Estilos Generales*/
.button {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block; /*bloque en linea*/
    font-size: 1.25em; /* 20px*/
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 40%; /*al agregar un inline-block puedo agregar un width*/
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 2px;
}
.rojo{
    background: #F13243;
}

.button img{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 50px;
}

.button span{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>
    <button class="button rojo"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/18/40/button-153684_960_720.png"/><span>hola</span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que te recomiendo es cambiar el `float:left` por `display:inline-block`, al hacer esto podrás utilizar la propiedad `vertical-align: center` y así el texto y la imagen se centran verticalmente en relación a su contenedor que en este caso es un botón.

Para que el botón se ajuste a la longitud del texto te recomiendo asignarle un `padding` al botón en todos sus lados.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*Estilos Generales*/
.button {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block; /*bloque en linea*/
    font-size: 1.25em; /* 20px*/
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 2px;
}
.rojo{
    background: #F13243;
}

.button img{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50px;
}

.button span{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>
    <button class="button rojo"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/18/40/button-153684_960_720.png"/><span>Hola mundo</span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Otra buena solución es usar `display: flex` en el botón y jugar con los valores de la propiedad `margin` tanto para la imagen como para el texto, así:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*Estilos Generales*/
.button {
    color: #000;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.25em; /* 20px*/
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 2px 2px;
}
.rojo{
    background: #F13243;
}

.button img{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50px;
}

.button span{
    margin: auto auto auto 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>
    <button class="button rojo"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/18/40/button-153684_960_720.png"/><span>Hola mundo</span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, te admiro. ¿Cómo podría o dónde aprender css? Porque veo que existen tantos estilos para aplicar y entender que a veces ni se por donde empezar.

Comment: @LeandroMorochoSoca pues realmente no sé, en internet existen muchos tutoriales, jejeje te recomiendo buscar en [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?ref=home&src=ukw&q=css) o directamente el de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/), de igual forma si necesitas ayuda puedes hacer tu pregunta acá, aunque veo que ya tienes suficiente reputación para poder interactuar en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), allí también te resolverán las dudas, puedes buscarme yo mantengo allí cada día.